# Benefits of using Model View Presenter design pattern (MVP)

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, design-patterns

Hi all I was looking for a link that would provide a list of benefits surrounding the MVP design pattern preferably in c#.

I was looking thoruhg the MSDN site but I find it hard to find there :(

could anyone please point me in a direction please.

Thank you kindly in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to be overwhelmed with information on MVP and it's relatives the guy to read is martin Fowler.

He's split MVP into two different patterns that he discusses in huge depth. I guess a good a place as any to start would be here:

[Retirement of MVP pattern (Martin Fowler)](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/ModelViewPresenter.html)

Answer (score 2):

Since Martin Fowler was first to catalopge this pattern I also think that the best way is to start there.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-view-presenter

Check also this site:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647543.aspx

Comparing to other patterns
http://nirajrules.wordpress.com/2009/07/18/mvc-vs-mvp-vs-mvvm/

http://geekswithblogs.net/dlussier/archive/2009/11/21/136454.aspx

Hope it helps.